# Matrix Algebra Manipulation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How does one show with full calculations:

$$S=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)(x_i-\bar x)^T = \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_i^T\right) - \bar x\bar x^T$$ where $$\bar x=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$$

Comment: What is the meaning of the $x$ with a hat on it?

Comment: And $ \hat{x_i} =  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i$ ? Or?

Comment: So, where there's $x_i$ with a hat, it should just be $x$ with a hat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(x_i-\bar x)^T=x_i^T-\bar x^T$, so

$$\begin{align*}
(x_i-\bar x)(x_i-\bar x)^T&=(x_i-\bar x)(x_i^T-\bar x^T)\\
&=x_ix_i^T-x_i\bar x^T-\bar xx_i^T+\bar x\bar x^T\;.
\end{align*}$$

If $\bar x=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nx_k$, then

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)(x_i-\bar x)^T&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_ix_i^T-x_i\bar x^T-\bar xx_i^T+\bar x\bar x^T\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_i^T-\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)\bar x^T-\bar x\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^T+n\bar x\bar x^T\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_i^T-n\bar x\bar x^T-\bar x(n\bar x^T)+n\bar x\bar x^T\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_i^T-n\bar x\bar x^T\;,
\end{align*}$$

which is the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_i (x_i-\bar x)(x_i-\bar x)^T = \sum_i (x_i-\bar x)(x_i^T-\bar x^T) = \sum_i x_i x_i^T -\bar x x_i^T -x_i \bar x^T + \bar x \bar x^T = \sum_i x_i x_i^T -\sum_i \bar x x_i^T - \sum_ix_i \bar x^T + \sum_i \bar x \bar x^T = \sum_i x_i x_i^T -n \bar x \bar x^T-n \bar x \bar x^T+ n \bar x \bar x^T$$

**NOTE**: You probably made a copying mistake, there should be no index to the mean $\bar x$.